# Why does SAS "merge" function overwrites observations with a bias?

Tags: sas

Here is my code

```
libname blood "C:\Users\owner\Desktop\SAS";   
data blood.donors1;
   input id type $ units;
   cards;
2304 o 16
1129 a 48
1129 a 50
1129 a 57
2486 b 63 
;
run;

data blood.donors2;
   input id code units;
   cards;
6488 65 27 
1129 63 32
5438 63 39
2304 61 45
1387 64 67
;
run; 

proc sort data=blood.donors1 out=blood.donors1;
   by id;
run;

proc sort data=blood.donors2 
           out=blood.donors2;
   by id;
run;

data blood.donorsmerge;
   merge blood.donors1 (in = indonors1) blood.donors2;
   by id; 
   if indonors1;
run;
```

---

Here is the result table `donorsmerge`

[image]

---

The row `1129 a 48` got COMPLETELY overwritten by `1129 63 32` . But rows `1129 a 50` and `1129 a 57` were PARTIALLY overwritten . Why ? I read the documentation . In my opinion the resulting data set should contain the `32` as I indicated  on the above image

Answer (score 2):

Because merge doesn't exactly work the way that it might seem - specifically, it does not operate like a SQL join.

Under the hood, how it works is that, for each by group, it reads the first row on the left side; then it finds a row that matches it.  Then, if there are more rows for that by group in the left-hand dataset, it goes to the next row.  If there is another row to match to from the right, it matches those two up; otherwise, it does nothing.  Continue until the last row of the by group.  After it writes out the last row of the by group but before it reads in the first row of the next by group, it clears out all variables.

The reason that each `by` group appears to have the same value for `code`, is that variables from `set`, `merge`, or `update` statements are automatically retained.  IE, they are not set to missing (except in between by groups, as a function of the `merge` statement).  Thus `code` is set to 63 for all three rows - it's set to 63 for the first row, and then not changed after that.

However, `units` appears on *both* datasets.  Thus, when the second row is brought in on the left, and there is no second row on the right, it keeps the value from the left-hand side.

If you want to overwrite a variable entirely, you need to `drop` the column from the left-hand side dataset.  If you want to overwrite it for matching rows and not overwrite it for nonmatching rows, and you have a many-to-one relationship (as you do here), you need to rename the variable in one dataset or the other, and use the `coalesce` or `coalescec` function (or logic) to set the variable appropriately.